# How to spread list inside string interpolation in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

How do I spread a list inside string interpolation in Kotlin?

Example, this would give an error saying "Expecting an expression"

```
fun getResult(lst: List<String>): String {
  return "${*lst.toTypedArray()}"
}
```

Expectation:

```
var lst = listOf("a", "b", "c")
```

expect getResult(lst) will return "a, b, c"

Comment: can you give an example of what you are expecting as result from getResult function.

Comment: What do you expect this to do?

Comment: Updated Description

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [joinToString()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/join-to-string.html) extension function, like this:

```kotlin
fun getResult(lst: List<String>) = lst.joinToString()
```

Note that `joinToString()` receives optional `separator` parameter, so you can use it to construct other similar strings. By default, `separator` is `", "`, so we didn't have to provide it in this case.

Furthermore, if this is the only thing `getResult()` function does, then I think you can really skip it and use `joinToString()` directly wherever you need it.